# Python sum over iterator to avoid memory issues

Tags: python, optimization, memory

Suppose that I have a couple of lists like these:

```
num = 100
configs = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(num, 8))
probs = np.random.rand(num)
```

Now, I use qutip to do one hot encoding and tensor products with `from qutip import tensor, basis`. Here `basis(N,i)` encodes the integer `i<N` in the one hot encoding for N classes, i.e. `basis(3, 0) = [1, 0, 0]`, or `basis(4,2) = [0, 0, 1, 0]`. Now, tensor does the Kronecker product, like `np.kron`, but can receive multiple arguments and perform `np.kron` iteratively on the list of arguments. Now I do the following:

```
states = [tensor(*[basis(5, i) for i in config]) for config in configs]
```

This can take a lot of memory, so a better option is to define it as a generator. Now, I need to compute this sum:

```
sum([p*state for p, state in zip(probs, states)])
```

I want to do this sum without consuming memory, i.e., the zip should consume only one element of probs and one element of states at a time. Then, the sum should be done one pair of elements at a time, in order to keep memory usage low. I want to do this as fast as possible, and consuming as few memory as possible. There `num` can be of the order of millions.

Comment: You have already defined the expressions as valid generators,  just remove the square brackets if you don't want to allocate a list of all the items.  `sum` and `zip` both accept generators expressions as arguments.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I will leave the question anyway XD someone could find this useful

Answer (score 0):

Since sum and zip receive generators, it suffices to change square brackets to regular parenthesis in order to define generators instead of lists.